# I want to store user entered vaule in some variable and use in another function or want to some opeartion on user input data

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, console, user-input

```
const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
})

readline.question('Enter number 1', function (a) {
  readline.question('Enter number 2', function (b) {
    //`i want to store user entered vaule in some variable and use in another function like sum`
    var one = a
    var two = b
    readline.close()
  })
})


function sum(one,two) {
  return one + two
}
```

My motive is to store user entered value and perform some operation on it or store to call another function with the input value. How can I achieve that?

In another language like C++ it is very simple but in node.js I am unable to figure it out.

*Please note that I do not want to use prompt, I want user to provide input from console*

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest way to use scoped variables within another function is to simply pass them in as arguments of the function. e.g.

```js
const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
})

readline.question('Enter number 1', function (a) {
  readline.question('Enter number 2', function (b) {
    //`i want to store user entered vaule in some variable and use in another function like sum`
    const result = sum(a, b);
    console.log(`The result of running my function is ${result}`);
    readline.close()
  })
})


function sum(first,second) {
  return first + second;
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way around what if i don't have function i just want to store input value

Comment: @Infinity Thats a hard question to answer because it's quite vague. But in general due to the asynchronous nature of node.js you are quite constrained when it comes to the idea global variables relying on async behaviour like IO. The problem is that even if you defined a variable outside of the scope of your callback function and then assigned it's value inside the callback function with there is no guarantee that the callback function will have run at the time that you use your variable outside of the callback scope. I think reading up on how node.js async works would be a good start.